# Upgrade a Python module in existing Docker image

Tags: docker, image, replace, containers, upgrade

I pull a docker image and when I run it, I realized that one of the python libraries is an
old version.

Can I create a Dockerfile by building on top on this existing image and then upgrade that library to latest version ?

What will be the Dockfile ?

Comment: Can you get the original source code for the image?  It might be cleaner to update the package dependencies in the original tree and `docker build` a new image than to amend the image with something different.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade an existing Docker Image using a `Dockerfile`.

Create a file called `requirements.txt` and on each line put the name of the packages you wish to upgrade, even if it's just the one:

###### requirements.txt

```
Flask
gunicorn
Pillow
```

Then create another file called `Dockerfile` with no extension in the same directory:

###### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

You can generate a Docker Image from this by using the command:

```sh
docker build --rm --no-cache --tag <tag>:<version> .
```

Replace `<tag>` with your new Docker Image name, and replace `<version>` with the version you want to assign it. If you are calling the Docker Image `koaystCustomPyTool` and want to omit the version, write the command like this:

```sh
docker build --rm --no-cache --tag koaystCustomPyTool .
```

Now when you run `docker images` you will see an output similar to this:

```sh
REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
koaystCustomPyTool   latest    536d44c69a88   1 minute ago   275MB
```

---

If you need to provide a custom command to execute the Docker Image when you run it, add a line at the end of the Dockerfile like this:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w", "2", "-b", ":8080", "poker.main:app"]
```

Here I have separated each command into it's own string value surrounded by double quotes `"` and wraped in square brackets `[` and `]`.